How can nginx be configured as reverse proxy for Blazor Server with SignalR hub
I have been running a Blazor Server application for multiple years. It's a fairly small and simple service that me and my friends are using. It has an nginx reverse proxy in-front of Kestrel and uses certbot for automatic issuing and renewal of Let's Encrypt certificates.
I'm starting the services using docker-compose and all containers are on the same network, which is bridged from the host.
The configuration for nginx looks like this:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include             /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-service-name:5000;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}

The ASP.NET container is listening on port 5000 like this:
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
It's been working well for the years that I've run the website.
Now I've decided to add a custom SignalR hub that can notify the clients of updates that another client does, to provide a more dynamic and smooth experience.
SignalR is bootstrapped like this in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        ["application/octet-stream"]);
});

app.UseResponseCompression();

app.MapHub<NotificationHub>(NotificationHub.HubUrl);

I have a single hub called NotificationHub with the specified hub URL of /notifications.
public class NotificationHub : Hub<INotificationClient>
{
    public const string HubUrl = "/notifications";
    
    public const string InviteCreatedMethod = "InviteCreated";
    public const string InviteAcceptedMethod = "InviteAccepted";

    private static readonly ILogger Log = Serilog.Log.ForContext<NotificationHub>();

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        Log.Debug("{ConnectionId} connected", Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? e)
    {
        Log.Debug(e, "{ConnectionId} disconnected", Context.ConnectionId);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(e);
    }
}

public interface INotificationClient
{
    Task InviteCreated(InviteCreatedNotification notification);
    Task InviteAccepted(InviteAcceptedNotification notification);
}

On the .razor Page the hub is subscribed to like this:
@implements IAsyncDisposable

@code {
    private HubConnection _hubConnection;

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        Log.Debug("Page {Page} disposing", nameof(Home));
        await _hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Log.Debug("Page {Page} initialized", nameof(Home));

        _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NotificationHub.HubUrl))
            .Build();
        
        _hubConnection.On<InviteCreatedNotification>(NotificationHub.InviteCreatedMethod, HandleInviteCreated);
        _hubConnection.On<InviteAcceptedNotification>(NotificationHub.InviteAcceptedMethod, HandleInviteAccepted);
        await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
    
    private void HandleInviteCreated(InviteCreatedNotification notification)
    {
        Log.Debug("{Notification} received", nameof(InviteCreatedNotification));
    }
    
    private void HandleInviteAccepted(InviteAcceptedNotification notification)
    {
        Log.Debug("{Notification} received", nameof(InviteAcceptedNotification));
    }
}

What happens when hosted behind nginx is that the browser will load for a long time, until timing out with a 504. The logs for nginx indicates that it never got a response from ASP.NET. The logs for ASP.NET looks like requests are handled normally.
When running locally I can see that I get requests to the /notifications URL:
[14:09:11 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:7108/notifications/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - null 0
[14:09:11 INF] Executing endpoint '/notifications/negotiate'

When running in production I don't see any logs that contains /notifications.
When nginx times out, this is what is logged:
2024/12/18 15:10:36 [error] 39#39: *1 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: [client public IP], server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.7:5000/", host: "www.example.com"

When the request is initially received, the logs for ASP.NET contains the following:
[15:09:36 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.example.com/ - null null
[15:09:36 INF] Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int64)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT a."Id", a."AccessFailedCount", a."ConcurrencyStamp", a."Email", a."EmailConfirmed", a."LockoutEnabled", a."LockoutEnd", a."NormalizedEmail", a."NormalizedUserName", a."PasswordHash", a."PhoneNumber", a."PhoneNumberConfirmed", a."SecurityStamp", a."TwoFactorEnabled", a."UserName"
FROM "AspNetUsers" AS a
WHERE a."Id" = @__p_0
LIMIT 1
[15:09:36 INF] Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__user_Id_0='?' (DbType = Int64)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT a."Id", a."ClaimType", a."ClaimValue", a."UserId"
FROM "AspNetUserClaims" AS a
WHERE a."UserId" = @__user_Id_0
[15:09:36 INF] Executing endpoint '/ (/)'
[15:09:36 DBG] Adding entry for 18b0d7e3-dde7-45b6-875b-efb27271616c/MudBlazor.MudPopoverProvider. 1 total observers after add.
[15:09:36 DBG] Updating entry for 18b0d7e3-dde7-45b6-875b-efb27271616c/MudBlazor.MudPopoverProvider. 1 total observers.
[15:09:36 DBG] Page Home initialized

The hub connection previously detailed is on page Home.
What I've tried:

Update the nginx configuration according to Microsoft's recommendations for using nginx together with ASP.NET.

map $http_connection $connection_upgrade {
  "~*Upgrade" $http_connection;
  default keep-alive;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://docker-service-name:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}


Explicitly configuring a location for the hub URL as suggested in an answer here on SO. I added it as a second location after the existing "/".

location /notifications {
    proxy_pass http://docker-service-name:5000;

    # Configure WebSockets
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    # Configure ServerSentEvents
    proxy_buffering off;

    # Configure LongPolling
    proxy_read_timeout 100s;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}


Update the nginx configuration according to Microsoft's recommendations for using nginx together with SignalR.

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include             /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-service-name:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /notifications {
        proxy_pass http://docker-service-name:5000;

        # Configuration for WebSockets
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        # Configuration for ServerSentEvents
        proxy_buffering off;

        # Configuration for LongPolling or if your KeepAliveInterval is longer than 60 seconds
        proxy_read_timeout 100s;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

All of these attempts result in the same behavior, timing out when trying to browse any page that is trying to establish a hub connection.
How can nginx be configured as a reverse proxy in-front of a Blazor server application utilizing SignalR?
